# (PHP) Check for valid day and month combination

Tags: php

Evening!

I'm trying to learn OO-programming in PHP and I want to check if a given day is valid in a given month. For example: 01-31-2016 is valid (because January has 31 days), 04-31-2016 is invalid (because April has only 30 days). I figured this can be done with `checkdate()`, but I'm struggling to make this work.

This is what I got so far:

```
<?php
class birthDate {
 public $birthday;
 public $birthmonth;
 public $birthyear;

 public function __construct($birthday, $birthmonth, $birthyear) {
    $this->birthday = $birthday;
    $this->birthmonth = $birthmonth;
    $this->birthyear = $birthyear;
}

 public function setBirthdate($birthday, $birthmonth, $birthyear) {
    if (checkdate($birthmonth, $birthday, $birthyear) == TRUE) {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;
        $this->birthmonth = $birthmonth;
        $this->birthyear = $birthyear;
    } else {
        $birthday = 0;
        $birthmonth = 0;
        $birthyear = 0;
  }
}

 public function getBirthdate() {
    if ($this->birthday == 0 && $this->birthmonth == 0 && $this->birthyear == 0) {
        $temp = "Not possible";
  } else {
        $temp  = $this->birthday   . "-";
        $temp .= $this->birthmonth . "-";
        $temp .= $this->birthyear;  
  }
return $temp;
}

 public function printBday() {
    echo "<strong>Birthday: \t</strong>" . $this->getBirthdate();
  }
}

$date = new birthDate(4, 31, 1991);
$date->printBday();
?>
```

I think I'm not using the checkdate function in the right way, but I can't figure it out. If the date is valid, the date should be printed. If the date is invalid, `$temp` should be printed. However, currently every date gets printed, whether it be valid or invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did yo get error ? if you get please add error report tou your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only problem is, that you don't call `setBirthdate()` in your Constructor.

Edit: So like TheDrot said, this should work:

```
<?php
class birthDate {
 public $birthday;
 public $birthmonth;
 public $birthyear;

 public function __construct($birthday, $birthmonth, $birthyear) {
    $this->setBirthdate($birthday, $birthmonth, $birthyear);
}

 public function setBirthdate($birthday, $birthmonth, $birthyear) {
    if (checkdate($birthmonth, $birthday, $birthyear) == TRUE) {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;
        $this->birthmonth = $birthmonth;
        $this->birthyear = $birthyear;
    } else {
        $this->birthday = 0;
        $this->birthmonth = 0;
        $this->birthyear = 0;
  }
}

 public function getBirthdate() {
    if ($this->birthday == 0 && $this->birthmonth == 0 && $this->birthyear == 0) {
        $temp = "Not possible";
  } else {
        $temp  = $this->birthday   . "-";
        $temp .= $this->birthmonth . "-";
        $temp .= $this->birthyear;  
  }
return $temp;
}

 public function printBday() {
    echo "<strong>Birthday: \t</strong>" . $this->getBirthdate();
  }
}

$date = new birthDate(4, 31, 1991);
$date->printBday();
?>
```

Comment: Also in this function's `else` block the variables set to 0 are local not class properties because of missing `$this->`

Comment: @Matthijs2504, Just to add one more thing in this answer, since you're accessing all the instance properties through *setter* and *getter* method, it's better if you make all the properties as `private`.

Answer (score 2):

or just you can use  [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) like this

```
bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

> **Parameters**
>
> **month**: The month is between 1 and 12 inclusive.
>
> **day**:  The day is within the allowed number of days for the given month.
>   Leap years are taken into consideration.
>
> **year**: The year is between 1 and 32767 inclusive.

and

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE if the date given is **valid**; otherwise returns **FALSE**.

```
$info1 = checkdate(4, 30, 1991);
var_dump($info1);
```

`bool(true)` if date are valid

```
$info2 = checkdate(4, 31, 1991);
var_dump($info2);
```

`bool(false)` if date are invalid